# Removing Base Window When Using Tkinter Python 3 (Askopenfiledialogue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first post on here, so bear with me as far as post etiquette goes. I've been struggling to get rid of the base Tkinter window that appears when I'm using the askopenfilename function of Tkinter. I've tried using Withdraw and destroy (in combination and alone) to fix this issue, but it seems to leave my code stuck in a loop and unable to continue to the next sections.

I have seen several solutions to this in Python 2, but I have no idea how they translate to python 3. Tkinter isn't a module I have a lot of experience with, so it is likely a simple oversight I am making.
Any suggestions or comments are much appreciated

Here is a sample of my code I am using (CSV module is for another section of my code)

```
import csv

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


root= Tk()
root.filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = r"\Users",title="Select A File", filetypes= [("Csv Files","*.csv")])
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.withdraw()` is the usual solution - and you don't need the call to `.mainloop()` if you're not going to be doing anything with Tkinter after the file dialog exits.

Comment: Using '''root.withdraw()''' followed by '''root.destroy()''' before the end of the mainloop has seemed to work. I go on to use tkinter a few more times in my code, but it's definitely handy to know that for future coding projects! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use withdraw to hide root window, deiconify to show root window

```py
import csv

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
# Hide Window
root.withdraw()

filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = r"\Users",title="Select A File", filetypes= [("Csv Files","*.csv")])

# Show Window
root.deiconify()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great! using root.withdraw seems to work. thank you so much!!